# What part of speech is the "be + verb" here? What tense are these sentences in?

Tags: grammar, tenses, parts-of-speech

> I shall have him be killed.
>
> She is to be stoned for adultery.

What are the constructions *be +verb* called, grammatically?  I feel like the above sentences are very adjectival in nature, more so than

> I shall have him killed.
>
> She will be stoned for adultery.

Is that correct?  Also, are both couplets of sentences in the exact same future tense?

Comment: I would not regard *I shall have him be killed* as correct. *She is to be stoned for adultery* puts the emphasis on stoning as a punishment rather than an event.

Comment: @Henry I believe **Robusto** told me it was grammatical, I was unsure myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction with *have* (and also with *make*) is usually referred to as a **causal** construction. Then *be + verb* is usually referred to simply as a **passive infinitive**. It isn't usually necessary to invent a special term for infinitives, passive or otherwise, in causal constructions.

As a side issue, it's worth noting that if you use *make*, the infinitive is introduced by *to* when it is passive but not when it is active. So the sentnces below marked with (*) are ungrammatical:

> I made him cry.
>
> *I made him to cry.
>
> *He was made cry.
>
> He was made *to* cry.

However, even in this case, there isn't usually a special term for the infinitive: it's just a (passive or active) infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

*Copula* is the word used for a connecting word, in particular a form of the verb *be* connecting a subject and complement.